# Can Eru see past, present and future all at once?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Eru Iluvatar lives outside the Universe and time, so can he see everything happening inside Ea all at one time and intervene in specific points in time?

Comment: Yes I can because Iive outside the Universe ;)

Comment: dont you mean outside Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear how the history of Eä is perceived in the Timeless Halls. It appears as though Ilúvatar *can* force the experience to be linear (emphasis mine):

> Ilúvatar said to [the Ainur]: 'Behold your Music!' And he showed to them a vision, giving to them sight where before was only hearing; arid they saw a new World made visible before them, and it was globed amid the Void, and it was sustained therein, but was not of it. **And as they looked and wondered this World began to unfold its history, and it seemed to them that it lived and grew.**
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* I *Ainulindalë*</sup>

But that's about all we can say conclusively. Since we know that he *does* intercede (and communicates with certain individuals), we have to conclude that he can interact with the World in a linear way. Whether that's how he actually perceives the World, though, is unknown.